# How to modally add a view to another view that is not in the view hierarchy iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers.

View controller 1 displays view controller 2 modally.

I dismiss view controller 2 with an animation.

I want this to animate away to reveal view controller 3 which would ideally be displayed modally from view controller 1.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I don't seem to be able to add any views to view controller 1 once view controller 2 is active, so I'm not sure what the best way to achieve this is.

Comment: Update your question with more details such as the relevant code causing your problem.

Comment: I don't think code is relevant here since I'm asking about best practices or what's even possible. I've updated with a bit more detail.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to change VC 1 while it is covered by modal VC 2? Are you saying that when you dismiss VC2, you want VC3 to be under it, so as VC2 animates away, VC3 will already be in place? If

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate on View Controller 2. View controller 1 will adhere to this delegate. When you dismiss View Controller 2, make a call to your delegate and simultaneously push view controller 3 from View Controller 1 without animation.

View Controller 1:

```
- (void)viewController2Dismissed
{
    ViewController3 *viewController3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewContrller3 animated:NO];
}
```

View Controller 2 Header:

```
@protocol ViewController2Delegate;

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)viewController2Dismissed;

@end
```

View Controller 2 Dismissal method:

```
- (IBAction)modalCloseButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate viewController2Dismissed];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In View Controller 1, you can alternatively present View Controller 3 modally after View Controller 2 has finished animating. This will animate View Controller 2 out then animate View Controller 3 in. If they are both modal view controllers, I wouldn't recommend attempting to find a way to get View Controller 3 to be displayed without animation behind View Controller 2 as it animates out. You want to give your users the indication that they're in a modal view controller and must interact with what's in view before they can return to the normal flow.